# react native offline bundle failing- event.js

Tags: android, react-native

While generating the android offline bundle am getting following error on my mac machine (npm - 8 , react native- 55.4.3 react 16.4.0)

Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Writing sourcemap output to: app/src/main/assets/index.android.map
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Done writing sourcemap output
bundle: Copying 9 asset files
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_images_back_chevron.png'